# Is it possible to add content automatically to WordPress posts, depending on their category?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress site where posts can belong to different categories.

I'm trying to make it so that every post in each category will include a certain image without it having to be done manually.

For example, if a post is created with category X, it should display image X. This should apply to every post in category X. If a post belongs to category Y, it should display image Y, and so on.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is easy.
You can use this plugins to get dynamic images for your each category.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/

check its documentation to display on single page.